# Joining tables with duplicate column names in spark

Tags: mysql, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to join multiple MySQL tables on spark. Some of these tables have duplicate column names (each table has an id field specific to that table).

If I try to run:

```
val myDF = session.read.jdbc("t1 inner join t2 on t1.t2_id = t2.id, queryTable, prop)
myDF.show
```

I get `java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous` since both tables have an id field (with different meanings)

I tried doing:

```
val t1DF = spark.read.jdbc(dbstring, "t1", "id").alias("a")
val t2DF = spark.read.jdbc(dbstring, "t2", "id").alias("b")
val joinedDF = t1DF.join(t2DF, Seq("a.t2_id", "b.id"))
  .selectExpr("ent.id as entity_id", "lnk.pagerank")
```

I got the error `org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: using columns ['t1.t2_id,'t2.id] can not be resolved given input columns: [..]` It would appear the analyzer doesn't know how to handle aliases.

The only option that seems to work is using a subquery:

```
spark.read.jdbc(dbstring, "(select t1.id as t1_id, t1.t2_id from 
t1 inner join t2 on t1.t2_id = t2.id) t", "t2_id")
```

Though in that case the the subquery will need to finish running before I can do any filters, making things un-acceptably slow and any query partitioning useless.

Spark does seem to have some internal way of disambiguating between between id's `id#528` and `id#570` but I can't figure out any way of referring to them in a select statement.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The only way I found to solve this out was to add a suffix on the column names. It looks something like this :

```
val t1DF = spark.read.jdbc(dbstring, "t1", "id").select(col("id").alias("id_t1"))
val t2DF = spark.read.jdbc(dbstring, "t2", "id").select(col("id").alias("id_t2"))

val joinedDF = t1DF.join(t2DF, t1DF("id_t1") === t2DF("id_t2"))
```